# systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server

Tags: apache, svn, debian, systemd, lsb

I have an Apache Web (version 2.4.10) server running on Debian 8 (Jessie). It is mainly  used as a SVN repository server.
It was working well since a few weeks, and suddenly, I got an internal error when attempting to list the SVN repos from a Web Browser as can be seen below:

[Apache Internal Error & Authentication](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vh5myl24y1mevzo/Capture.JPG?dl=0)

As you can see, authentication is still working fine.

I ran the 2 following commands:
systemctl status apache2.service
and
journalctl -xn

[commands](https://www.dropbox.com/s/etwcyl8y1lgfe03/Capture3.JPG?dl=0)

But that doesn't help me much, maybe I'm missing something?
I did NOT modify any configuration file recently related to Apache (or even anything else for that matter): neither the main apache conf file nor any vHost conf file.
I tried restarting Apache, it does restart but the Web Server still encounters an internal error.

error.log:

```
[Sun Jan 31 18:36:17.372502 2016] [core:notice] [pid 27449:tid 140087289513856] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Jan 31 18:37:07.641329 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 27449:tid 140087289513856] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Jan 31 18:38:31.156131 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 1049:tid 140557851056000] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.8.
[Sun Jan 31 18:38:31.156330 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 1049:tid 140557851056000] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.9.

[Sun Jan 31 18:38:31.157222 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1049:tid 140557851056000] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) SVN/1.8.10 OpenSSL/1.0.1k mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.9 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Sun Jan 31 18:38:31.157241 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1049:tid 140557851056000] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

[Sun Jan 31 19:21:39.401930 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1049:tid 140557851056000] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

[Sun Jan 31 19:22:35.038612 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 1313:tid 139813423814528] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.8.

[Sun Jan 31 19:22:35.038672 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 1313:tid 139813423814528] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.9.

[Sun Jan 31 19:22:35.039592 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1313:tid 139813423814528] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) SVN/1.8.10 OpenSSL/1.0.1k mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.9 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Sun Jan 31 19:22:35.039611 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1313:tid 139813423814528] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

[Sun Jan 31 19:24:57.303622 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1313:tid 139813423814528] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

[Sun Jan 31 19:26:20.336578 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 1050:tid 140178825381760] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.8.

[Sun Jan 31 19:26:20.336805 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 1050:tid 140178825381760] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.9.

[Sun Jan 31 19:26:20.337601 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1050:tid 140178825381760] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) SVN/1.8.10 OpenSSL/1.0.1k mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.9 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Sun Jan 31 19:26:20.337617 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1050:tid 140178825381760] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

[Sun Jan 31 19:31:24.663351 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1050:tid 140178825381760] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

[Sun Jan 31 19:31:25.827873 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 1208:tid 139958437914496] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.8.

[Sun Jan 31 19:31:25.827919 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 1208:tid 139958437914496] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.9.

[Sun Jan 31 19:31:25.828655 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1208:tid 139958437914496] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) SVN/1.8.10 OpenSSL/1.0.1k mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.9 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Sun Jan 31 19:31:25.828679 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1208:tid 139958437914496] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Could that come from the Python version that mod_wsgi is running which differs from what mod_wsgi is apparently expecting?

Answer (score 0):

try two commands blow:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2 

sudo apt-get install apache2
```

after that use systemctl status apache2 to check you apache's status

Answer (score 0):

These commands solved my problem:

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2 

sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Note: if you use `purge` as another answer, you should set all Apache config again, But when you use `remove` it just removes core of Apache and after installing you don't need anything more.